# Android service Service crashed 2 times, stopping: ServiceRecord

Tags: android, service, android-activity, android-service, activity-manager

I am writing and testing an android app where I need to restart app on multiple crashes. 
The restart code works fine, but after 2 crashes the service does not restart, and I see following message in the logs

```
06-13 02:31:02.098: W/ActivityManager(2117): Service crashed 2 times, stopping: ServiceRecord{42b5b6a0
```

Looks like service restart after 2 crashes is not being allowed by AcitivityManager.

Is there some API using which we can change this number from 2 to something else ?

A sample app to reproduce this is available here

https://github.com/devendram/servicecrashdemo

Logcat output available here

https://gist.github.com/devendram/5c5259d3f91fd8409e7b#file-gistfile1-txt-L1754

Comment: There is not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @AlexLockwood what additional info can be added to assist in answering?

Comment: Code would be a very good place to start.

Comment: Post the logs from the crashes, and more logs as well.

Comment: What restart mechanism are you using?  if your Service returns START_STICKY in the onStartCommand call it should really handle this for you...

Comment: So when the service crashes, are you sure it's been cleaned up properly?  I.E references to the binder etc.. are handled?  I have a feeling that the approach you're using is leaving cruff in the vm and its getting confused.

Comment: I updated the original question with link to logcat output and a simple demo app which reproduces this

Answer (score 0):

So I can't swear this applies, but it's one of the better examples of a "ServiceRecord" i found online:

*Removed Dead link to hi-android.info, which now advertises suspicious investment products*

---

Also

http://justanapplication.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/dgc_18/

Has some good discussions of the ServiceRecord.  From what I'm seen it looks like Android tracks your service, and in order to avoid a number of issues, stops allowing the service to start if it crashes repeatedly.  The constants I see don't quite match 2, but I suspect that to be the problem.

Can you find a way to avoid the crashes?  Try-Catch for example?  This is costly but it would avoid the crashing and colliding....

Otherwise - why is your service crashing so frequently?  Why does it need to?

Comment: I need to demo recovery ability of the service, hence trying to get it restarted everytime there is a crash. Try catch is not an option because we want the app to crash and restart

Comment: Ok, well can you provide more information?  How are you restarting it?  Are you using return START_STICKY in your binder?  Or are you manually restarting?

Comment: I tried START_STICKY earlier but now I am restarting in exception handler. I added that default exception handler code to the question.

Comment: I see that.  Did you have this issue with start_sticky?

Comment: I had some other issues with START_STICKY unrelated to this. I need to check if START_STICKY gives this issue as well. I'll update the info as comment here .

Comment: What were those issues?  Start_sticky is the built in way to handle this situation.

Comment: Just checked with START_STICKY. I hit the same issue. After two crashes, service does not start .  06-13 02:31:02.098: W/ActivityManager(2117): Service crashed 2 times, stopping: ServiceRecord{42b5b6a0

Comment: Can you post a "mininum reproducible code" example that I can work with?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the android source code, I found an attribute of ProcessRecord which may solve the problem, **isPersistent()**. Then I dumped the package info of all packages with adb. The result looked as following:

```
Package [com.android.phone] (fa7158b):                           
  userId=1001                                                    
  sharedUser=SharedUserSetting{3eab065 android.uid.phone/1001}   
  pkg=Package{4db66c com.android.phone}                          
  codePath=/system/priv-app/TeleService                          
  resourcePath=/system/priv-app/TeleService                      
  legacyNativeLibraryDir=/system/priv-app/TeleService/lib        
  primaryCpuAbi=null                                             
  secondaryCpuAbi=null                                           
  versionCode=29 minSdk=29 targetSdk=29                          
  versionName=10                                                 
  splits=[base]                                                  
  apkSigningVersion=3                                            
  applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{58dac1b com.android.phone}     
  flags=[ SYSTEM HAS_CODE PERSISTENT ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ]
```

The flag **PERSISTENT** was interesting and I thought it might be set in AndroidManifest.xml. So I checked [all available attributes of tag application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element), and finally got the attribute **android:persistent** to solve this problem.
By the way, I'm an android system service programmer who writes android applications signed with platform key. I'm not sure if it works also for normal ones.